# Why is the given smooth vector field non zero?

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $S^n$ be the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ where n is odd.   Assume $n = 2k-1$ where $k \in \Bbb N$ and consider the vector field on $S^n$ given by 
$$X_p = \left( -x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \right)+\left( -x_4 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} + x_3 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_4} \right)+ \dots+\left( -x_{2k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2k-1}} + x_{2k-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2k}} \right)$$

This is a smooth vector field on $S^n$ because the $x_i$ are smooth for each $i$. But I'm not able to deduce the fact that it's a non-zero vector field which I'm told it is. I'm new to differential geometry and I hope someone can explain clearly as to why it's a non-trivial smooth vector field.

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are linearly independent. So, for it to be zero one must have $x_1=x_2=...=x_{2k-1}=0$, but this point is not on the sphere.

Comment: Where are you using the fact that n is odd?

Comment: @JohnMitchell I am not using it. You are using it when you proved that $X_p$ is a vector field on $S^n$.